# Proof: For $ a\in\mathbb{R}^{\geq0}, \quad \text{then} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (a-n+1)\frac{a^n}{n!}\geq 0 $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

I will be grateful if someone can help me with the following proof.

$$
\forall a\in\mathbb{R}^{\geq0},\quad \text{then} \quad \left\{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (a-n+1)\frac{a^n}{n!}\right\}\geq 0
$$

Comment: If you want to ask $2$ questions, add it as a new sentence, don't just change the original question you're asking. People use this site as a reference too, so there's no point writing over questions that you've asked.

Comment: I will edit it and post the new one. thanks for your point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (a-n+1)\frac{a^n}{n!}=a\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a^n}{n!}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a^n}{(n-1)!}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a^n}{n!}=ae^a-a\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}+e^a=ae^a-ae^a+e^a=e^a>0$$

Comment: Where in the proof $a \ge 0$ is used?

Comment: This result is valid for all $a$